# (React native) how to load new data and add to component (recycler list view) when reached at the end of first data set

Tags: javascript, android, listview, react-native

This is for react native, I want to fetch second page from api as soon as the end of the first page is on the screen and show on recycler list view (https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) similar to infinite scroll. How can i achieve this, I tried setting a callback at onEndReached props, but the callback fires as soon as the initial page is loaded. (The initial page is 2 screen heights long).

Answer (score 1):

Don't mount `RecyclerListView` without data. That might lead to incorrect `onEndReached`. It is same as `ListView` contracts, when the callback fires create a new `dataProvider` and pass to RLV and it'll update.

Answer (score 0):

for the endless listview, you can look this document. 
https://medium.com/react-native-development/build-a-chat-app-with-firebase-and-redux-part-1-8a2197fb0f88

But, in official React Native document, you better not to use a ListView but use FlatList instead. Because it's outdated.